# In circular motion is the angular velocity vector always perpendicular to centripetal acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, vectors, rotational-kinematics

- In circular motion is the angular velocity vector always perpendicular to centripetal acceleration?
- Are there any exceptions?
- Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular velocity can be defined as:

$$ \omega = \frac{\mathbf r \times \mathbf v}{|\mathbf r|^2} $$

So the angular velocity vector is always at right angles to $\mathbf r$.

If we consider circular motion, where $\mathbf r$ is the position vector from the centre of the circle, then centripetal acceleration is, by definition, always in the same direction as $\mathbf r$. That means the angular velocity is always at right angles to the centripetal acceleration.

Comment: Why it is defined this way only?

Answer (score 3):

The angular velocity vector is defined as pointing *out* of the paper (it is the axis about which the angular velocity rotates). It will always be perpendicular to any vector drawn *on* the paper.

Answer (score 0):

Analysisng from the first point:

1) Assuming it is referring to planar circular motion with fixed axis, the moment of inertia tensor of the system reduces to a single scalar variable ($I_o$ suppose). In other words, we know that the angular momentum about a fixed point O in space of the particle undergoing circular motion, is given by :

$L_o = \vec r_o \times m\vec v$.There are cases, when it is not perpendicular to the centripetal acceleration.

2) For better understanding, consider the following diagram:

[image]

We chose the point O as shown. By the definition of angular momentum above, clearly, $L_o$ is a rotating vector in space, perpendicular to both $\vec v$ and $\vec r_o$ at any instant. Now, we also know that:

$\vec L_o = I_o.\vec \omega$, which implies that $\vec \omega $ is in the same direction as $\vec L_o$. Clearly, $\vec \omega$ is not perpendicular to the centripetal force in this case, which point in the radial direction in the plane of the circle.

**NOTE**: I may be wrong, but i could not find any flaws in my deduction. Forgive me if it is stupid, but please point out any mistake, and i will remove this answer immediately.

Comment: John Rennie's answer does not take into account the situations, where the reference frame is NOT the center. Am i wrong in this explanation? Note, this reduces to the obvious case in his answer above, when O coincides with the circle's center.

Comment: While taking the moment of the linear velocity according to point O, shouldn't the perpendicular lever arm be on the axis of O instead of the distance labelled ro in the diagram?